# Apache adds /var/www to js file path

Tags: url, apache-http-server

I'v got a problem. Client has VPS and we transfered magento system to it.

The problem is that if for example path to magento is /var/www/magento and there is some file in it like /var/www/magento/file.js(for example) then on frontend it tries to load:

```
(host)/var/www/magento/file.js
```

but not

```
(host)/magento/file.js
```

How I can fix this?

**UPDATE 1**

Strange thing:
CSS files are listed properly, but JS file use wrong path.

Answer (score 3):

Check that `var` and `media` folders have write permissions.
Give **777** rights on them and clear the contents of `/var/cache` of your Magento folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.htaccess` for a proper re-write setup. You may need to properly define the `RewriteBase` directive or modify `RewriteRule` settings. In either case references should not be absolute but instead relative to the docroot or HTTP URL, respectively.

Also the URL or SEO configuration may be mis-configured in Magento (disclosure: not intricately familiar with Magento so I'm not sure if it defines a site URL like Wordpress and Joomla do).

Comment: Redargind to magento all URL's are configured properly. Rewrite base is not used at all. The strange thing: CSS resources paths are proper, but js files are not properly listed!